# Drupal html code being shown in title blocks when it shouldn't

Tags: php, drupal

I am using Drupal 9 and when I try and add some code between 'h1' tags like 'hello world' in the title of the Highlight Box along with some regular text like 'Title' the 'h1' tags show when they shouldn't. Does anyone know how to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're typing in HTML, at the top right of the text box, do you have "Source" selected? That will tell Drupal that you're using HTML instead of plaintext.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I didn't have it selected.